# Is it ok to copy a domain in weblogic in situations where we need to have the same configuration for dev/testing purposes?

Tags: dns, weblogic

I am aware of weblogic templates, but out of curiosity I wanted to know, Is it ok to copy a domain in weblogic in situations where we need to have the same configuration? I have already done the same and have been successful in testing my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can get away with doing this, but there are a couple of more reliable (and scriptable) ways to migrate the same configuration through the development team, or to create new deployment environments.

The domain template builder lets you build your own custom domain template from an existing domain: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13179_01/common/docs92/tempbuild/starttb.html

There's a couple of ways to get it done with WLST, as well:

You can use configToScript to spit out an entire WLST script (and properties file) to recreate the exact configuration you've got, or...

You can use readDomain and writeDomain in offline mode to recreate an existing configuration in a new domain:

readDomain: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1003638

writeDomain: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1003688

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to copy the domains over and it worked exceptionally well prior to WebLogic 9.2. However, there are some weird bugs that pop up for versions that are using the portal for the console.

Also, after copying the file you would want to make sure that all listen addresses and ports have been modified accordingly so that your local managed server doesn't attempt to connect to the production administration server on startup.